# iOS static library doesn't have 64 bit support, how can I get it to run on 64 bit device?

Tags: ios

I ran the following command:

`xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info IDTECH_UniMag.a`

Architectures in the fat file: IDTECH_UniMag.a are: armv6 armv7 armv7s i386

How can I get this static library to work on a 64 bit device/emulator. I know it is possible because the sample app I was given is able to run in a 64 bit emulator, but I cannot figure out what build settings is allowing this.

Comment: Hey Chris, can you let me know how you solved the probleem. I am facing the same issue. How do I run it on arm64 devices?

Comment: I followed the steps in the answer exactly as written

Answer (score 4):

32 bit apps can run in the 64 bit simulator or device. The sample app is probably 32 bit.

You have two choices:

1. Build your app 32 bit only by setting **Architectures** (or ARCHS) of the target or project from **Standard Architectures (including 64-bit)** to **Standard Architectures**. (Target probably fails back to project, so if it's a simple project you probably want to change it in project.)
2. Get a 32/64 bit version of the library.

Note that Apple requires 64-bit executables for all new apps as of February 1, 2015.

Comment: How do I tell if the app is 32/64 bit? What do I need to do to change?

Comment: added some details :)